# Selling site - How to transfer PayPal subscribers?

Tags: paypal, transfer

I have a website that has hundreds of active PayPal subscribers, and I am putting it out on the market. I have found out that it is not possible to transfer subscribers from one account to another. It is also against the terms to change ownership of an account.

PayPal suggests cancelling all current subscribers and making them sign up again under the new owner's account. Surely there has to be a better way?

Has anyone had any experience in a situation like this, if so, how did you handle it? Has anyone just outright gave the buyer the current PayPal account that was linked to the subscriptions?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Paypal suggesting that all of your users sign-up again is rather ridiculous. I am sure this is not the first time this situation has come up. Surely they have a better answer than that!? Have you talked to them over the phone? Perhaps asking for a supervisor would be advised.

Comment: Is this PayPal account setup as a business account or a personal account?

Comment: You better ask the Paypal Community Forum About it

Answer (score 1):

Adrian, a PayPal employee and community forum administrator has answered this question on a post asked in February 2012. He has confirmed that **'subscriptions and billing agreements are non-transferable without re-subscribing'**.
It seems that because the customers will be paying into a different account, a new subscription must be established, and so the best you can do to avoid losing customers or payments is to carefully manage the transition process.

---

> "As the buyers would technically be paying a different account,
>   subscriptions and billing agreements are non-transferable without
>   re-subscribing.  Understandably, you'll want to avoid subscriber loss,
>   so you may want to switch over existing buttons to direct them to your
>   new account, and then either transition your existing subscribers en
>   masse at some point (after much advanced  notice) or allow them to
>   expire and then re-sign up." - *PayPal_Adrian, PayPal Community Help Forum*

Source: [PayPal Community Forum: Moving Subscriptions from one account to another](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Products-Archive/Moving-subscriptions-from-one-account-to-another/td-p/433141?profile.language=en)